# Could C-3PO have sat in one of the Millenium Falcon's quad laser cannons and shot down pursuing TIE Fighters?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, the-empire-strikes-back, millennium-falcon, c-3po

Could C-3PO have sat in one of the Millenium Falcon's quad laser cannons and shot down pursuing TIE Fighters?

This assumes of course that he could climb up/down a ladder.

[image]

Comment: *"There's been some terrible mistake. I'm programmed for etiquette, not destruction!"*

Comment: Hmm. He fumbles a hand-blaster in Star Wars #1 (2015) but he doesn't seem to have any prohibition in at least *threatening* violence.

Comment: Not to mention I recall him being physically rather clumsy -- could he have gotten up or down a ladder without falling and breaking something?

Comment: @ZeissIkon, I think he could manage going up or down a ladder, but it would take him longer to do it than a human.

Comment: He'd go faster if you quit looking up his can.

Comment: He would’ve. If someone had asked him nicely 

Comment: I'd rather trust R2 for that

Comment: Why, please? We all know he could have, and what might any Answer mean?

Comment: Are you sure that is C3PO?  I don't recognize him without his red arm.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, well, if he is able to shoot down TIE Fighters, perhaps the next Star Wars movie could have him doing so. I think most Star Wars fans would love to see him being a hero by taking out TIE Fighters.

Comment: Did you notice C3PO was greatly more capable than R2D2, who like various others of his kind is sometimes seen running a weapon station?

If you think there's a valid Question here, why send off a scenario?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

C-3PO does precisely this in [*Star Wars Rebel Force #4, Firefight*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rebel_Force:_Firefight) *

> **Fire,” Leia ordered, hoping that C-3PO had absorbed her quick tutorial
> on operating the quad laser cannons. Laserfire launched toward the
> Star Destroyer, scoring a direct hit on its shield generator dome.**
> Leia quickly guided the Millennium Falcon out of the Destroyer’s
> firing range and took a quick survey of the situation. Three battered
> ships — one out of commission, two intact but taking heavy fire.
>
> She tuned the comm to a Rebel frequency, hoping to pick up evidence
> that her friends were inside. As she did so, **she accelerated and
> hurtled toward the remaining TIE fighter, which was lurking just
> beneath one of the strange ships, about to fire. Two quick blasts from
> the laser cannons blew it into debris.**

C-3PO is surprisingly accurate, even at speed and even against a TIE-fighter.

<sub><sup>* Note that this is a 'Legends' novel.</sup></sub>

Comment: Give it enough time and Dave Filoni might make this canon

Comment: How does this make any sense though? C-3PO's movements are slow and jerky, how could he possibly have the dexterity and reaction speed for something like this? Did they at least lampshade it or something?

Comment: @terdon - Finn takes out a TIE without even having the ability to move the gun.

Comment: Fair. But that required the ship to be aimed carefully (IIRC) not "hurtling towards the TIE". I call sloppy writing! :P

Comment: @terdon - A badly written Scholastic Star Wars book? Never!

Comment: @terdon, C-3PO was able to pilot Senator Amidala's ship to Mustafar in the Revenge of the Sith, so it's possible that he could be fast enough to operate the laser turret on the Millenium Falcon.

Comment: @user57467 - He also pilots Luke's landspeeder.

Comment: @user57467 my personal handwavium there was that he did so through some sort of direct linking. More importantly, that shouldn't require any quick, accurate motions or dexterity. The landspeeder... is harder to explain. But the level of coordination and reflexes required to accurately swivel those big guns around and shoot at things seems much, much higher.

Comment: @terdon Yeah.  He just lacks the smoothness of motion--if the TIE fighter blundered into the path of his gun I would expect him to nail it with great accuracy (he knows where the bolts will go) but I would not expect him to get the gun on target very well.  Deadly shots but not very many of them.

Comment: Would that be Quad Laser Cannon, @Boolean? ;)